# Xcode 7 Error message “could not inspect application package”

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am building and running an app to my iPhone but after it compiles I get a pop up error from Xcode "App Install failed: Could not inspect the application package."

After getting the error, the console does not have any errors. The app works in the simulator but not when I send it to my phone. I have tried the following solutions:

- Cleaned the package
- Deleted Derived Data
- The name of the app does not have any non Roman characters
- I have not copied any files into my application
- There is no precompiled code.
- Updated Provisioning Profiles
- Entitlements match in the provisioning profile
- Got new iOS Development and iOS Distribution Certificates
- Updated Developer ID Application and Developer ID Installer
- Restarted both iPhone and Macbook Pro

I am using Xcode 7.0 on a Macbook Pro running 10.10.5 with an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.0.2

Any Ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you removed the application from iPhone, and installed it again?

Comment: I have removed it from the iPhone but I can not reinstall it because it is failing.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen with Xcode 7 and iOS 9 if a product name contains non-latin characters. In this case changing product name to the one with only latin characters for debug builds fixes this problem.

Comment: The name of my project is only latin characters.